# About the numpy.linspace

Tags: python, numpy

I have read a code is like this
`x = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)[:, None]`

I know the meaning of `np.linspace(0,100,10)`

But I don't know what does '[:,None]' mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[:, None]` adds an extra axis making a two-dimensional the array of shape `(10, 1)`. A more explicit version would be:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)[:, np.newaxis]
```